# Gitlab CI\CD schedule pipline Interval

Tags: git, gitlab, scheduled-tasks, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I created a .gitlab-ci.yml file in my Git project and I would like it to run every 5 minutes.

I created a new schedule in gitlab.com ( CI/ CD -> schedules -> new schedule) and used custom Interval Pattern with the pattern - * /5 * * * *

[image: created a new schedule]
[image: Interval Pattern]

But this is not working, I saw that the pipeline run every hour and not every 5 minutes as I expected.

I used the pipeline schedules documentation
and I saw that maybe the reason is that schedules are handled by
Sidekiq and I need to edit gitlab.rb file -
[image]

I can't find what is this "gitlab.rb file", I tried to created it manually in my project, and tried to put this file in my project under etc/gitlab/, and this not working for me.

Please help me with this issue, if you know what I should do about the gitlab.rb file or do you have another idea of how to run ci/cd every 5 minutes.

Thank you!

Comment: `and not every 5 minutes as I ` And `* /5` is every 5 hours. Try `/5 * * * *`

Comment: still not working :( I tried even to put * * * * * (it should be every minute and unfortunately it doesn't work)

Comment: 5 * * * * should work

Comment: it is not working..

Comment: I guess it is not a syntax error..

Answer (score 4):

As you've [found in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html#advanced-configuration), how frequently a schedule is run is partially determined by the cron.

By default, the cron is run on the 19th minute of every hour, which means, it won't run more than once an hour unless the default has been changed.

The `gitlab.rb` file that needs to be edited is part of the GitLab installation (as the other poster mentioned), so you would either need to [follow the configuration instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html) to edit the file, or talk to whomever is the GitLab administrator for the instance you're using to change it.

For reference, the [GitLab.com settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#gitlab-cicd) page lists the cron frequency for the SaaS version of GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

`gitlab.rb` file is part of Gitlab installation, i.e. not part of the project.